# Android studio is not prompting the errors

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio for flutter development. I did some error (missing semi colon) but its not showing up the error. I did try invalidate cache & restart and restart my MacBook but no use.

for eg.,
see the picture below, where i randomly typed jhg iki and all. but the error not been shown up.

[image]

My Android Studio version:

```
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683, built on May 18, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.6.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 3072M
Cores: 4
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true, ide.instant.shutdown=false
Non-Bundled Plugins: Dart (212.5744), io.flutter (69.0.2)
```

Comment: try to invalidate caches and restart

Comment: i did try already.. the thing is, only for that particular project its like not showing.. for other projects its showing. something fishy